# panic: http: multiple registrations for / (root path)

Tags: go, httprouter

I am trying to start two http server on different ports, but unable to use the same pattern:

```
handlerFunc1 := http.HandlerFunc(hello1)
http.Handle("/", handlerFunc1)
server1 := &http.Server{
    Addr:    "localhost:8081",
    Handler: handlerFunc1,
}
go server1.ListenAndServe()

http.HandleFunc("/", hello2)
go http.ListenAndServe(":8082", nil)
```

Do you know how, I have tried using(as you can see) `http.Server` and `http.ListenAndServe`

Comment: Use a different `http.ServeMux` instance for each server. The ServeMux type implements the http.Handler interface, so you can use that as the last argument to `http.ListenAndServe` or as the `Handler` field of the `http.Server` struct. The `http.Handle` and `http.HandleFunc` both use the [`http.DefaultServeMux`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.19.2#DefaultServeMux) and the ServeMux type allows only one handler per pattern.

Comment: [`http.Handle`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/net/http/server.go;l=2546) registers a handler on the same ([default](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/net/http/server.go;drc=7e72d384d66f48a78289edc6a7d1dc6ab878f990;l=2305)) [`http.ServeMux`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/net/http/server.go;drc=7e72d384d66f48a78289edc6a7d1dc6ab878f990;l=2289). You'll need to create at least one custom `ServeMux`.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/oRJLRgfFBP3

Comment: Remove this line `http.Handle("/", handlerFunc1)`.   There's no point in registering a handler in the default serve mux when the server does not use a serve mux.

Answer (score 3):

Well for any other progressive developer this works:

```
mux1 := http.NewServeMux()
mux1.HandleFunc("/", hello1)
go http.ListenAndServe(":8081", mux1)


mux2 := http.NewServeMux()
mux2.HandleFunc("/", hello2)
go http.ListenAndServe(":8082", mux2)
```

Thanks to [@mkopriva's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74184912/panic-http-multiple-registrations-for-root-path/74185093#comment130978743_74184912):

> Use a different `http.ServeMux` instance for each server. The ServeMux type implements the http.Handler interface, so you can use that as the last argument to `http.ListenAndServe` or as the `Handler` field of the `http.Server` struct. The `http.Handle` and `http.HandleFunc` both use the [`http.DefaultServeMux`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.19.2#DefaultServeMux) and the ServeMux type allows only one handler per pattern.